# how to bind dynamically image to the windows phone image control

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am consuming .net web-service in my windows phone app.
Here I binding XML data to the controls,I am unable to display image.
C#:

```
eSchooltrack.ServiceReference5.EST_WebServicesSoapClient obj = new EST_WebServicesSoapClient();

 obj.GetLoginUserDetailsCompleted+=new EventHandler<GetLoginUserDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(obj_GetLoginUserDetailsCompleted);
         obj.GetLoginUserDetailsAsync(loginid);

  }

    private void obj_GetLoginUserDetailsCompleted(object sender, eSchooltrack.ServiceReference5.GetLoginUserDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)

    {
        XElement xmlNews = XElement.Parse(e.Result.ToString());
        image1.Source=GetImage(xmlNews.Element("ProfileImage").Value);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

depending upon the return type of the GetImage function

1) if its BitmapImage, then it should work, else the Image its returning is null

2) if its Uri do `image1.Source=new BitmapImage(GetImage(xmlNews.Element("ProfileImage").Value));`

3) if its a string do `image1.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri(GetImage(xmlNews.Element("ProfileImage").Value)));`

I hope it helps. Do note, if still the image is not being displayed, you should check the returning value of the function != null before assigning it.